# Calculate Average Price of Market Order in a thin order book:

Tags: trading, markets, market-order

Take the following UST/USDC order book:

[image]

Suppose I were to place a market order to buy $10,000 USDC worth of UST. How would I calculate the average price the order would be filled at? Would this math calculate it correctly?

[image]

Where Avg Price = sumproduct( (2), (3) ) / Total

Or would it all be filled at 1.0003? I'm pretty sure it would be the former but I guess I'm not sure since the order book displays the current price as 1.0003. Would my market order get broken into the four orders I have in the second picture and fill each one individually or is it done some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You have some small rounding errors and one bad typo:

25,481.719 time 1.0013 isn't equal to 7,046
It's 7,034.1653

Other than that, yes, the average price would be 1.00120 .